# How can i get the last inserted id of a dynamic mutiple field and save to another database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, symfony

Hello i have a form that is dynamic.. meaning you can add multiple input fields in the form and under each form there is also a sub dynamic form .
and in my db i have a invoice table and a section table, the invoice table serves as the main field while section is the sub field. now am trying to get the last inserted id of the data sent to the db. since its dynamic only one data is getting returned.

i tried this code tho

```
foreach ($services as $key => $value) {
        $inv = new Invoice();
        $inv->receiver_email = $email;
        $inv->receiver_info = $info;
        $inv->render = $services[$key];
        $inv->total = $total;
        $inv->invoice = $invoice;
        $inv->tax = $tax;

        $inv->save();
        $invoice_id = array($inv->id);
        print_r($invoice_id);

}
foreach ($invoice_id as $idd => $va) {
foreach($service as $key => $value){
    $dataforsec = [
        'service' => $service[$key],
        'rate' => $rate[$key],
        'invoice_id' => $va,
    ];
    // dd($dataforsec);
    DB::table('sections')->insert($dataforsec);
    }
}
```

this saves only the last id. but its dynamic i can send in three data at a time i need to get the three data also.. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Change `$invoice_id = array($inv->id);` to `$invoice_id[] = $inv->id;`.

Dont forget to declare default value `$invoice_id = [];`

Comment: Hi, i did what you recommended but i only got just one id .. i mean i was expecting to get 3,4 but got all data with invoice id of 4 only.

Comment: i got this response from the $invoice_id[] 
Array ( [0] => 5 ) Array ( [0] => 6 )

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can just simplify your loop in this case to fasten the process.

```
foreach ($services as $key => $value) {
    $inv = new Invoice();
    $inv->receiver_email = $email;
    $inv->receiver_info = $info;
    $inv->render = $services[$key];
    $inv->total = $total;
    $inv->invoice = $invoice;
    $inv->tax = $tax;
    $inv->save();
    //$invoice_id = array($inv->id);
    print_r($invoice_id);

    $dataforsec = [];
    foreach($service as $key => $value){
      $dataforsec = [
         'service' => $service[$key],
         'rate' => $rate[$key],
         'invoice_id' => $inv->id, // the Id from the parent.
      ];
    }
    DB::table('sections')->insert($dataforsec);
}
```

Comment: Hello, i have dynamic input field but the above code tends to just save the last row with repeated value tho the id re different ... am trying to get all service with respective id from the first table sir